# s3cmd S3 Endpoint and DNS-Style bucket is missing on configure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am using on s3cmd for reactJS web upload, I am doing configure and it able to access without issue but I notice there is missing on s3 endpoint and DNS bucket host

[image]

it should show like this. as you can see s3 endpoint and DNS bucket host( this screenshot are old and it on internal developer document) 
[image]

and I'm able to access to the S3 Bucket list without any issue but my problem is upload react web

```
s3cmd --delete-removed --cf-invalidate --cf-invalidate-default-index sync build/* s3://test-website-staging –verbose
```

then the error return

```
ERROR: Parameter problem: Invalid source/destination: 'build/asset-manifest.json' 'build/favicon.ico' 'build/favicon.png' 'build/index.html' 'build/manifest.json' 'build/service-worker.js' 'build/static' 's3://test-website-staging' '–verbose'
```

this code I have used for last 6 months without any issue, since the last week, I have to reinstall ubuntu and download currently version of  s3cmd and the s3 endpoint, Bucket and location are no longer appear on the configure :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it  fixed due to older version on the s3cmd 1.6.1, as done upgrade to s3cmd 2.02